# ruby migration rolled back but get error when run migration again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

This is the error I get when running a migration in a RoR application:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "bulk_bill" of relation "questionnaires" already exists
```

A little background:
I rolled back a migration so that I could change the default setting for a column.
Once I ran the migration again I got the error above.

I can see in the postgresql table in development that the column does exist. I have a data in the tables and in the bulk_bill column it has it's default set to false.

What are the recommended steps I need to take so that I so the migration can be run successfully.
I am a beginner in ruby and find the ruby documentation still a little hard to follow.

```
    def up
      add_column :questionnaires, :bulk_bill, :boolean, :default => false
    end 

    def down
      remove_column :pnp_questionnaires, :bulk_bill
    end
```

Comment: Could you show us this migration (Both up and down methods)

Comment: def up
    add_column :questionnaires, :bulk_bill, :boolean, :default => false
  end
  def down
    remove_column :pnp_questionnaires, :bulk_bill
  end                                                                I then changed the default to nil and tried to run

Comment: @maggs You should edit your question to describe futher information, it is a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

In your `up` method you're creating column on `questionaries` table, and in your down method you are removing it from `pnp_questionaries`. Remove column does not raise an excepton if table doesn't exists, hence you have your problem.

Simplest solution:

1. Comment out `add_column` from up.
2. Run migrations (yes, run empty migration).
3. Fix your `down` method to remove `questionaries` table.
4. Rollback migration.
5. Uncomment your `up` method.

UPDATE:

My bad - point 3 was to be 'remove column from questionaries', not 'remove table'.

You need to rerun the migration which created the table (hopefuly you didn't alter it in a meantime). Go to the given migration, comment out `down` method body, and run `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=xxxxxxx` where `xxxxxx` is the timestamp in this migration filename.

Comment: PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "questionnaires" does not exist             Now the questionnaires table does not exist and so the column can't be added. I have an earlier migration that created the questionnaire table so I assume this does not run to recreate the questionnaire table?

Comment: def up
    add_column :questionnaires, :bulk_bill, :boolean, :default => nil
  end
  def down
    drop_table :questionnaires
  end

Comment: How did you rollback? `rake db:rollback` it should only rollback single migration.

Comment: used rake db:rollback

Comment: Ah, I wrote it wrong. Point 3 - remove the column from, not the table. Eh, I'll update the answer.

Comment: How can I recreate the table.  rollup a few steps?

Comment: unable to run command:  -bash: db:migration:redo: command not found  I added only the timestamp without the name of the migration for the migration redo command. This is correct?

Comment: @maggs I think you've mistakenly droped your table. How many times did you use the rollback command?

Comment: @RafaelRamosBravin yes I did mistakenly drop the questionaires table.  I tried to run db:migration:redo VERSION=xxxxxxx where xxxxxx is the timestamp in this migration filename.  This is command is able to be found so I am trying to find out how to create the table.  for Rollback I only went once

Comment: @maggs Did your `db:migrate:redo` (notice that you wrote 'migration') command raise an exception?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your rollback question.  I have tried to roll back and forward the migration several times but only rolled back 1 step

Comment: @RafaelRamosBravin no exception raised just command not found

Comment: @maggs Oh okay, so that's not the problems source. But as I said, you used `db:migration:redo` instead of `db:migrate:redo`

Comment: @maggs - You also need to add `rake` - full command is 'rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=xxxxxxxx'

Comment: typo the command I used was db:migrate:redo VERSION=20120912122332 I will run again with rake

Comment: @maggs I think you used `migration` because the error message you've posted mentions it: `unable to run command: -bash: db:migration:redo`

Comment: @RafaelRamosBravin,@BroiSatse  command has run by me paying close attention to spelling and wording