# ruby dropped table but can't recreate with migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-migrations

A table was dropped in a rollback migration. The migration itself was changed so that the down section dropped the table.
I ran the migration that created the table again

```
rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20120912122332

==  CreateQuestionnaires: reverting =====================================
-- drop_table("questionnaires")
rake aborted!
PG::Error: ERROR:  table "questionnaires" does not exist
```

it appears as if before redoing the migration it is trying to drop the table. As it does not exist the rest of the migration can't be run.
Is this correct and if so how can I recreate the table

Comment: please show your migration...

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding `redo`. It is a `down` followed by `up`.

Answer (score 1):

The table is already dropped.

I would suggest you to use

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=20120912122332
```

As redo will again try to rollback, i.e., drop the table which you have already dropped in the earlier stage. Hence, you are getting the failure.

Comment: This command is trying to revert the migrations after the    VERSION=20120912122332 and is failing on some of them

Comment: This command would only run the migration with version `20120912122332 ` unless you have not specified the version in the command.

Comment: Make sure you have only one migration file with version prefix 20120912122332 db/migrate folder

Comment: this is the command that I ran : rake db:migrate VERSION=20120912122332  I have scanned the migration list and there is only 1 migration with this timestamp

Comment: Also see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208636/ruby-migration-rolled-back-but-get-error-when-run-migration-again

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the migration and do the [DROP TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droptable.html) manually, that would let you add an IF EXISTS to ignore the DROP TABLE if the table isn't there:

```
def down
  connection.execute('drop table if exists questionnaires')
end
```